# Elastic Pipelines: Skip Import On Failure

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-pipeline

Individual processors in an Elastic pipelines [have an `on_failure` attribute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/handling-failure-in-pipelines.html).  This allows you to handle a failure/error in a pipeline.  The example in the docs show setting an additional field on your document.

```
{
  "description" : "my first pipeline with handled exceptions",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "rename" : {
        "field" : "foo",
        "to" : "bar",
        "on_failure" : [
          {
            "set" : {
              "field" : "error.message",
              "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to tell the pipeline to SKIP importing a document if any processors in the pipeline fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "hijack" the [`drop` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/drop-processor.html) to skip either directly in the `on_failure` step (no need for `_ingest.on_failure_message` if you're aborting anyways):

```
{
  "description": "my first pipeline with handled exceptions",
  "processors": [
    {
      "rename" : {
        "field" : "foo",
        "target_field": "bar",
        "on_failure" : [
          {
            "drop" : {
              "if" : "true"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

or use it as a separate processor, perhaps at the very end, after `ctx.error` has been set by *any* of the processors' `on_failure` handlers:

```
{
  "description": "my first pipeline with handled exceptions",
  "processors": [
    {
      "rename" : {
        "field" : "foo",
        "to" : "bar",
        "on_failure" : [
          {
            "set" : {
              "field" : "error.message",
              "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "drop": {
        "if": "ctx.error.size() != null"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Both of these will result in a `noop` when the pipeline is applied.