# Elasticsearch: how do you ingest a hex string as a number type (integer or long)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I saw here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/32213 that Elasticsearch added support for ingest of hex strings as type long or integer for version 7.0.0 and moving forward.

But when I use my Elasticsearch 7.3 and set the type to "integer" or "long" and then try to index a value of "0x1234" I get an error[1].

[1] this is from python:

> RequestError: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse field [KEYWORD] of type [long] in document with id '#############'. Preview of field's value: 0x1234'")

### Elasticsearch: how do you ingest a hex string as a number type (integer or long)?

Maybe there is some sort of config value to turn this feature on... but I couldn't find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PR you're referencing concerns ingest pipelines -- a [collection of tools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) to help prepare document values *before* they're inserted into ES.

But good that you've mentioned it -- the [`convert` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/convert-processor.html) is a suitable solution here:

1. Store a pipeline that converts the string content of the field `KEYWORD` into a `long`:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/hex-converter
{
  "description": "converts the content of the KEYWORD field to a long",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "KEYWORD",
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Use this pipeline as you insert the docs:

```
POST myindex/_doc?pipeline=hex-converter
{
  "KEYWORD": "0x1234"
}
```

3. Verify that it worked -- we're expecting 4660 as the result:

```
POST myindex/_search
```

---

Pipelines make some quite powerful operations possible: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404331/8160318) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65190172/8160318).